# How can I get this eval() call to work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I have some javascript that goes out and fetches a javascript "class" on another xhtml page. The remote javascript looks something like the following:

```
    (function() {
        this.init = function() {
            jQuery("#__BALLOONS__tabs").tabs();
        };
    })
```

After this is fetched into this.javascript, I try to eval it and instantiate:

```
   this.javascript = eval("(" + this.javascript + ")");
   this.javascript = new this.javascript();
   this.javascript.init();
```

Of course, this works perfectly in all browsers except IE. In IE, it fails at the eval line. Does anyone have suggestions on how I can make this work in IE or an alternative.

Thanks, Pete

Comment: You don't need `eval` for that. Or did I misunderstood it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
eval("this.javascript = (" + this.javascript + ")");
```

...?

Comment: Well there is no eval in IE. I did try this with window.execScript, however, but it doesn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: There is no eval in IE!?!?  Of course there is!  eval is discouraged, but is part of the JS/EcmaScript specification, and has been in IE since IE3 (JScript version 1): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z6exc9e.aspx

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong to have the perception that eval isn't available.

Comment: Thanks Lee, so if that's the case I don't understand why eval returns null only in IE.

Comment: Hi Lee, this ended up working after I made the variable local. Don't ask me why it didn't like the instance var. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @slypete, thank you very much for that 'working after i made the variable local' remark, it literally saved my butt. I hate IE!!

Answer (score 2):

This worked with good browsers and bad ones (which means ie) :

```
var code_evaled;
function eval_global(codetoeval) {
    if (window.execScript)
        window.execScript('code_evaled = ' + '(' + codetoeval + ')',''); // execScript doesn’t return anything
    else
        code_evaled = eval(codetoeval);
    return code_evaled;
}
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

(eval is not an object method in IE). So what to do? The answer turns out to be that you can use a proprietary IE method window.execScript to eval code.

```
function loadMyFuncModule(var stufftoeval) {
  var dj_global = this; // global scope reference
  if (window.execScript) {

    window.execScript("(" + stufftoeval + ")");

    return null; // execScript doesn’t return anything
  }
  return dj_global.eval ? dj_global.eval(stufftoeval) : eval(stufftoeval);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this. According to Microsoft's docs, this method always returns null. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536420(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, but you can access it in the global scope regardless (see my edit)

Comment: When I say access "it" i'm referring to the object you've created by evalling.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is still not a complete answer. The "class" that I'm loading (not object) has no name. How would I instantiate this class that I loaded if I have no handle?

Comment: Try what out? I need to create an instance. var object = new (???)(); As you can see, handle is missing.

Comment: Don't be a dick Pete, just try it, trust me ;)

Comment: Hey Pete, you can use Jquery eval too, that'll fix the x-browser issues

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic. How would you do it? I have no idea. There is no handle.

Answer (score 0):

If worst truly comes to worst, something like this may work:

```
var self = this;
funcid = "callback" + Math.random();
window[funcid] = function(javascript) {
  delete window[funcid];
  self.javascript = javascript;
  self.javascript = new self.javascript();
  self.javascript.init();
}
document.write("<script language='javascript'>" +
               "window." + funcid + "(" +
                 "(" + this.javascript + "));" +
               "</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of eval() with IE, and the function with "window.execScript" didn't worked for me.
The solution I found to get arrays in javascript from a page (php in my case), was to use some JSON.

// myfeed.php

```
return json_encode($myarray);
```

// myjs.js

```
$.getJSON('myfeed.php',function(data){dataAlreadyEvaled = data;});
```

This needs no eval() function, if it helps anyone...