# json return data not working in IE or Chrome

Tags: php, json, uploadify

I have problems returning JSON data after using Uploadify.

This code works in Firefox, but not in IE 9 or Google Chrome.
This is the script script for Uploadify:

```
     jQuery("#uploadify_gallery").uploadify({
        'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
        'uploader'       : siteURL + '/wp-content/plugins/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : siteURL + '/wp-content/plugins/uploadify/uploadify_gallery.php',
        'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png',
        'auto'           : true,
        'multi'          : true,
        'method'         : 'POST',
        'buttonImg'      : siteURL + '/wp-content/themes/storelocator/img/buttons/img_upload_grey_bg.png',
        'cancelImg'      : siteURL + '/wp-content/plugins/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'queueSizeLimit' : 20,
        'scriptData'     : {'entity':jQuery('#entity').val(),'entity_id':jQuery('#entity_id').val()},
        'onComplete'     : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

          alert('test'); // <-- THIS WORKS 

          //This makes the json response readable
          var result = eval("(" + response + ")");
          alert(result.toSource()); // <-- this never fires
        },
      });
```

This is the code I test with in `uploadify_gallery.php`:

```
$res = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($res);
```

It worked yesterday, and I've got it working on

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Comment: Eval is bad. Avoid it at all costs.  Also, what does the JSON that the server is returning to your script look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the value returned by the server and verify that it is valid JSON (using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) for example).

After that you can use [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert the response string into an object.

Comment: Yes, I discovered this and that's what I'm using now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

eval(); isn't a good choice, it's considered pretty bad, since it won't work in Internet Explorer, at least the older ones. Check this out

[How can I get this eval() call to work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050840/how-can-i-get-this-eval-call-to-work-in-ie)

http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval

You'll get the response as a json object, so instead of eval, just loop through it with an each

```
$(response).each(function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

For more information on each, check out http://api.jquery.com/each/